# Django form validation with values_list in ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, forms

I have a form like this:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    genus = forms.RegexField(
        regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]+$',
        required=False,
    )  
    species = forms.RegexField(
        regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]+$',
        required=False,
    )
    island_group = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        required=False,
        queryset=Locality.objects.values_list('islandgroup', flat=True).distinct('islandgroup'),
```

Now, my form fails validation on the the `island_group` field as I am not returning model objects. I need to return the `values_list` to get the distinct entries. There is a bit more to this form which is why I don't want to use a model form.

My question is: what is the best way to get my form to validate?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Is `islandgroup` an another model? Why don't use that model for a queryset? If you need to filter only actual info, you can add some `annotate` with `Locality` counts and filter on them too.

Comment: The form actually comprises fields which correspond to several different models. iskandgroup is a field in the Locality model.

Comment: You can't do `ModelChoiceField` for queryset which do not return `model` objects. So make it a queryset of `islandgroup` model or make it a simple `ChoiceField` and retrieve an object on `clean_island_group()`

Answer (score 0):

Why not override the save method: call some validation function before actual save?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my solution now is to use the ChoiceField instead of the ModelChoiceField. I believe this makes sense, since we do not want the user to select model instances, but distinct attribute values throughout one table column and the same attribute might well correspond to several model instances.

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    # get the distinct attributes from one column
    entries = Locality.objects.values_list('islandgroup', flat=True).distinct('islandgroup')
    # change the entries to a valid format for choice field
    locality_choices = [(e, e) for e in entries]
    # the actual choice field
    island_group = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=False,
        choices=locality_choices)
```

This way Django's inbuilt validation performs exactly what we want, i.e. checking whether a member of the set of all possible attributes from one column was selected.